# How to redirect to another page if user not in that team in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a function that make user who try to get into team page when they are not in that team.

Here is my following code:

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const fetchCurrentUser = () => {
    axios
      .get(`/api/v1/profiles/profile/${serverUserData.publicId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data);
        if (
          res.data.Teams.length <= 0
          // ||
          // res.data.Teams.map((team) => team.public_team_id !== teamProfileId)
        ) {
          router.push("/profile");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  };
```

So I am trying to achieve `res.data.Teams.map((team) => team.public_team_id !== teamProfileId`

example: if that user have 3-4 teams but not this team so they cant get into this team page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is check if the `Teams` has a `team` matching `teamProfileId` then let them access else not.

You can check with [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
if (res.data.Teams.some(team => team.public_team_id !== teamProfileId)) {
  router.push("/profile");
}
```

It will return `true` if the condition passes, i.e no matching `teamProfileId`; else returns `false`.